# Expresso Store limit certain products to member group

Tags: expresso-store

I'm building a webshop with hair care products, certain products however shouldn't be available to all members. We plan to have two member groups, regular buyers and haircare professionals.

So what I need to do is mark certain products to only be available to a specific member group(professionals).

What's the easiest way to achieve this? All the products are currently in one channel and I would prefer to keep them this way.

Should I just make a simple switch fieldtype? Is it possible to just write some type of "if member group = 4 AND fieldtype = yes" statement?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways you could go about it, you could indeed use a P&T Switch or P&T Pill field in your channel then have something along the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="100"}
 {if logged_in_member_group == 4 && professionals_switch == "yes"}
  {!-- show Professional items here --}
  {title} -- {price}
 {/if}
 {if professionals_switch == "no"}
  {!-- if you still want to show non-professional items to the professionals you will need to have it here. This will also show only non-professional items to other users --}
  {title} -- {price}
 {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You could also do the same with checking a member group and to see if a category has been set.

This approach should work without a problem if you are not using pagination or outputting the products in an ordered list since EE would actually be grabbing all of the products but only showing a portion based upon the conditionals being true which would have some pages resulting in less content or missing numbers.